# Ethereum Wallet balance zero

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets

I have a full Ethereum Wallet, so I funded it with bitcoin and I saw the transaction in the etherscan website. But my balance (after 1 day) is still 0. what can I do? There are only 105 blocks left and the transacion block was already syncronized.

Comment: Can only send Bitcoin to a Bitcoin address

Comment: It sounds like something right happened. If you saw something on the Etherscan website and you originally sent Bitcoin, there must have been some sort of translation between the two chains going on. Mist has Shapeshift integration (not sure about Parity and can't check at the moment); was that what you used?

Comment: What does he mean by a "full" ethereum wallet? I think no wallet can be full, except perhaps if he owns all the ether, which is impossible.

Comment: @Distic I think "full" here means as opposed to "light".

Comment: It could be. But it could also be any non-online wallet.

Answer (score 1):

You sent a bitcoin to your ethereum wallet? If so, you might have lost it and sent it to a bitcoin wallet with the same address. Bitcoins need to be converted to Ethereum through a service like Shape Shift.